# Convert image to base 64 string with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base64, encode

I want to convert an image to base 64 with Laravel. I get the image from a form .
I tried this in my controller:

```
public function newEvent(Request $request){
    $parametre =$request->all();

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        if($request->file('image')->isValid()) {
            try {
                $file = $request->file('image');
                $image = base64_encode($file);
                echo $image;


            } catch (FileNotFoundException $e) {
                echo "catch";

            }
        }
    }
```

I get this only:

> L3RtcC9waHBya0NqQlQ=

Comment: `$request->file()` doesn't return the actual file content but an instance of `UploadedFile`. You need to load the actual file to convert it. Try: `$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')->path()));`

Comment: please to make the inverse operation? base64 to image

Comment: `base64_decode($image)`? Did the first comment help you?

Comment: for the first i think this work base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));

Comment: now i want to decode and save but this dont work file(base64_decode($image))->move("images", $name);

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer so you can accept it, since it solved your main question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Your variable `$image` contains the image data base64 encoded. If you decode it, it's just binary data, not a PHP-class.

Comment: this workerd  file_put_contents("images/".$name, base64_decode($image));

Comment: Yes, you're simply storing the binary data as a file. Not sure why you needed to base64 encode it first, though. You could just have used the `->move()`-method on the original UploadedFile-class to store it as a file.

Comment: i an sending it to an external API with guzzle

Comment: Ah. ok. But since my answer actually did solve your initial question, please accept the answer below so other SO members knows that this question has been answered.

Comment: In Laravel `base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')->getRealPath()))` this works too.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Laravel's `$request->file()` doesn't return the actual file content. It returns an instance of the `UploadedFile`-class.

You need to load the actual file to be able to convert it:

```
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')->pat‌​h()));
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this one? I just want to know I am little bit confused why you need to convert it?

Comment: @Biax20 they might want to store it in the database as a string, just as one example

Answer (score 26):

It worked for me in the following way:

```
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));
```

I eliminated this part `->pat‌​h();`

Comment: When I tried this, I got this error : "file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty".

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to append file type.

Example for pdf :

```
$file = "data:@file/pdf;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));
```

Example for image :

```
$file = "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//html code
<input type="file" name="EmployeeImage">

//laravel controller or PHP code
$file = $request->file('EmployeeImage');
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)); 

// display base64 image
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $image . '" />'; exit();
```