# Get the image from laravel database to angular frontend

Tags: angular, laravel

i have ecommerce project and i need to view the images of the products and i don't know how to get it with angular and i wish anyone can help me
the store function in laravel

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:100', 'display' => 'required|string|max:100', 'ram' => 'required|string|max:100', 'img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png',
        'storage' => 'required|string|max:100', 'rear_cam' => 'required|string|max:200', 'front_cam' => 'required|string|max:200',
        'price' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return response()->json($errors);
    }

    $img = $request->file('img');
    $ext = $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $img_name = 'product-' . uniqid() . ".$ext";
    $img->move(public_path('uploads/books/'), $img_name);

    $name = $request->name;
    $brand_id = $request->brand_id;
    $display = $request->display;
    $ram = $request->ram;
    $storage = $request->storage;
    $rear_cam = $request->rear_cam;
    $front_cam = $request->front_cam;
    $price = $request->price;
    $product = Product::create(['name' => $name, 'brand_id' => $brand_id, 'display' => $display, 'img' => $img_name, 'ram' => $ram, 'storage' => $storage, 'rear_cam' => $rear_cam, 'front_cam' => $front_cam, 'price' => $price]);

    $success = 'Product created successfully';

    return response()->json($success);
}
```

angular html

```
<td><img [src]="'./../../../../../../../xampp/htdocs/mobitech/public/uploads/books/' + product.img" class="w-100"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a column in your database after storing your image get a **static URL** of it
2. save it to the database
3. pass it to your front end to use that static URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 representation, which is a group of binary-to-text encoding schemes that represent binary data in an ASCII string, this string can be stored directly to database as a normal string.

You can find here how to convert the image to base64 with Laravel [Convert image to base 64 string with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206992/convert-image-to-base-64-string-with-laravel/46207246)

And in angular, you need to just put that string to the in the src attribute of an img tag.
if you are storing the result in a variable called img64 you can do this

```
<td><img [src]="img64" class="w-100"></td>
```

Comment: and i don't need to store the name of the image?

Comment: You mean a title like that you could put in the alt attribute ?

Comment: If so, you can store it in a separate variable

Answer (score 0):

To view an image in Laravel Blade you can simply use:

```
<td><img [src]="{{asset('uploads/books'.'/'.+ $product->img)}}" class="w-100"></td>
```